# Line spacing doesn't seem to be enough

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, design

I was looking a [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27988128/height-and-width-not-working-on-css-content-property) question when OP was clarifying their question in the comments.

They had correctly added formatting to their comment, (code snippet).

However, this was how it viewed on my machine:

[image]

And so their 'under scores' didn't appear before the word 'content', as this overlapped with their name.

Could this be looked into further? Or is this my machine?

Comment: It's definitely your machine. But not only yours ;-(

Comment: Looks fine in FF 35 and IE 11. Maybe you could post your machine specs.

Comment: Chrome V.34 / V.38. Was in work and laptop both are having the issues.

Comment: I can't repro this. But another person using Ubuntu firefox reported similar problem. I have reduced the padding in the OP box a bit. See it helps. The change will go live tomorrow AM.

Comment: Hey @jbutler483, we have deployed some changes here - can you confirm it resolved the issue for you?

Comment: @NickCraver: Spot on. Cheers :P It was more 'to let you know', rathe than an issue here. But cheers :)

Comment: @jbutler483 gotcha, thanks for the follow-up! I'll close this one out.

Comment: @NickCraver: Cheers for that. Did you eveer get looking at the 'show snippet icon' (I posted a prev. question here). Doesn't seem to show?